# How to generate java doc and sources for a library created by me using maven

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, m2eclipse

This might be small question but I am not able to find answer to it. I wrote a library called Utilities and used java doc  style comments. Using maven (m2e plugin in eclipse). I am using maven install option. I am getting a jar file and i am pushing the jar file to a central repository and reusing the same library in another project. I am able to use the lib and complete my project successfully but when I do ctrl click I am not able to see the library code from my project. I am also not able to see the arguments description when i hover my mouse on the methods.

I know that it is because My project is not finding sources and java doc .

So How can i generate sources , java doc for my library and attach them to my project using maven.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:

- [Cookbook: How to attach source and javadoc artifacts?](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the maven sources plugin found at this link:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/usage.html

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must deploy sources and javadoc JARs along with library JAR. AFAIR you can either use:

```
$ mvn clean javadoc:jar source:jar deploy
```

or:

```
$ mvn clean deploy -DperformRelease=true
```

## See also:

- [How to deploy Javadoc jar file?](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/faq.html#How_to_deploy_Javadoc_jar_file)
- [Maven 2: Deploying Javadoc with your project](http://garbuz.com/2010/08/01/maven-2-deploying-javadoc-with-your-project/)
- [Maven 2: Deploying Project Sources](http://garbuz.com/2010/07/31/maven-2-deploying-project-sources/)
- [Attaching javadocs and sources to Maven install/deploy](http://sea36.blogspot.no/2009/02/attaching-javadocs-and-sources-to-maven.html)